# Convert string of hex value into []byte representation

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have seen multiple questions to convert String to byte array, but what I want is to cast to byte[].
So that for instance, if I have `a := "68656c6c6f20776f726c64"`, if I do `[]byte(a)`, it will convert each number into its hex value, but what I want is that it is directly interpreted as hex directly, so that I have `[]byte b = [68, 65, 6c, etc.]`

Is there any other way different to iterating the string and every 2 characters appending them to the `[]byte`?

Comment: `hex.DecodeString`

Comment: `byte[]` is meaningless in Go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37506631/13860

Comment: No, that is conversion. I want it to be stored as it is. Exactly the same. Hex decoding would be if I have `68 65 6c 6c 6f` and the output I want is `hello`, but I have `68 65 6c 6c 6f` and I want to store inside an array exactly that but inside a `byte[]`, so that I would have `[68, 65, 6c, 6c, 6f]`. Correct me if I am mistaken, but I think that is not hex decoding.

Comment: Again: `byte[]` is meaningless in Go.

Comment: That absolutely is hex decoding.

Comment: it is impossible to have a byte array composed of values such `[68, 65, 6c, 6c, 6f]` because byte is an integer `0<=255`. `6c` is the hex representation of `L` or `108` http://www.asciitable.com/ based on adrian answer see this https://play.golang.org/p/uRXn1rCmz0L

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A string *is* a byte array. Casting one to the other gets what you're seeing; the character `a` has an integer value (97, or 61 in hexadecimal), and you're getting the byte array that makes up the string of characters. If you want the string `"ff"` to become the integer 255 (`ff` in hexadecimal), that's not casting, that's parsing (decoding) the string based on a particular logic (i.e. that the string is made up of ASCII representations of hexadecimal digits). To do that you want to use an appropriate decoder, i.e. the standard library's [`hex.DecodeString`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#Decode) as mh-cbon suggested:

```
src := []byte("68656c6c6f20776f726c64")

dst := make([]byte, hex.DecodedLen(len(src)))
n, err := hex.Decode(dst, src)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%s\n", dst[:n])
```

Comment: I see, my mistake. I am still learning how Go works, I am used to python, where there are no types. Thank you for the explanation.